# CAPL Evaluation write in a Matrix

Tags: capl, canoe

I want to write the evaluation of CAPL Node in a matrix. Now I have my evaluation just in write windows and they are more than 10000 line. therefore I want to write in a matrix with limit of lines and columns.

Any idea?

```
on message 0x4490 
{
  if(this.A ==2 && A_TEMP == 3)
  {
    diff3_0_A= timeNowint64();  
    addTimeToMeasurementStartTime(timeNowNS(), time);
    write(" %02d/%02d/%02d %02d:%02d:%02d.%-3d               Aa                               %d                               %d                            %d ms"
        ,time[5]+1, time[4], time[6]-100, time[3], time[2], time[1], time[0]
        ,this.A
        ,A_TEMP
        ,diff3_0_A-diff0_3_A);
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe some screen shots of how your output is looking like and how you want it to look like could be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I had to do the same some years ago.

As you are stating to use CANoe, you have the Test Feature Set (TFS).

First change your code to use this.

Either you use the Test Feature Set directly to generate table, or, if it needs to be much more customized, go with the following I did:

If you use the test features, you will get an XML test report.

Then I used a XML Stylesheet Transformation to generate a HTML table out of it.

I could also have generated Office Open XML for Excel.